# I'm getting a negative part in Time complexity function. Is the solution of the Time complexity of this Recurrence relation correct?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence, wolframalpha

I tried to find the Time complexity of this Recurrence relation [T(n) = 7T(n/2) + n^2] by using Akra Bazzi method .But I am not sure if it's correct or not. Can someone please review the solution and let me know if I made any mistake anywhere?

[This is my solution of the Recurrence relation [T(n) = 7T(n/2) + n^2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFQev.jpg)

My Time complexity answer is matching with the [WolframAlpha calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=T%5Bn%5D%3D%3D7T%5Bn%2F2%5D%2Bn%5E2). But I am not sure if I did the internal workings correctly since I'm getting a negative part in the Time complexity function.

Comment: If I use Mathematica on `Table[(-4*(4^(Log[n]/Log[2])-7^(Log[n]/Log[2])))/3+7^(-1+ Log[n]/Log[2])*C[1],{n,1,6}]//N,{n,1,6}]` then I get `{0.1429*C[1],4.+C[1],17.1331+ 3.1214*C[1],44.+ 7.*C[1],88.9017+13.0967*C[1],155.9320+21.8499*C[1]}` So it looks like the negatives disappear. If you could provide an extra boundary condition then that C[1] would be resolved. WolframAlpha understands things like `{T[n]=7T[n/2]+n^2,T[1]=2}`

Comment: @Bill thanks a lot. I used Akra Bazzi method for this question. I attached the solution to the question. If possible, can you kindly give check whether there is any mistake in my solution? That would be very helpful. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

I searched on your doubt , inside teh integrate value ubr getting ignore it less dominating term.
0[2 (x^log2^7)]
Ignore constan, value of log2^7 = 2.8
Therefore,

0(n^2.8)
approximately 0(n^3)